# Add more values to one cell in c# table

Tags: c#

I have a table in C# like this

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Color", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Brand", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Seats", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Fuel consumption", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Max. speed", typeof(int));


        table.Rows.Add();
```

and I don't know how to add values to row if I want to have more than one value in one cell, e.g. in color column would be blue, green, yellow as a 3 separated strings and in seats would be 2, 4, 5, 8 as an integers...

Comment: Ok, thank you... think I can manage it now...

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than 1 value in a row then why have a string as datatype. Instead have a array Datatype like int[].

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Color", typeof(int[]));
table.Columns.Add("Brand", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Seats", typeof(int[]));
table.Columns.Add("Fuel consumption", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Max. speed", typeof(int));
```

Now when you add rows like this

```
DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
dr[0] = "";
dr[1] = new int[] {20,24,44}; //For RGB values
.
.
dr[4] = new int[] {2,4,5,8}; // For Seat Numbers
.
.
table.AddRow(dr);
```

When Retrieving you can do so

```
int[] val = (int[])table[0][2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add separator to distinguish between multiple values in a column. e.g. add separator as comma (,) while adding data

Answer (score 0):

You probably will need to change the datatype of the column to string

```
table.Columns.Add("Seats", typeof(string));
```

and than add comma separated values.